# Rails ActiveRecord trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

Please help with ActiveRecord testing. Trying my first Rails 3.1.0 project. There I have model named "Account", described like:

**migration.rb**:

```
def self.up
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :type
      t.references :user

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :accounts, :user_id
end
```

**account_model.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_length_of :name, :within => 15..255
  validates_numericality_of :type
end
```

And if i'm making in Rspec :

```
account = Account.new(:type => 1)
account.type.should == 1
```

I've got test result:

```
Failure/Error: account.type.should == 1
       expected: 1
            got: nil (using ==)
```

I tried Account creation in console, and every time i'm assigning any integer value as 'type', i got 'nil'. Not assigned value. What I'm making wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'type' is a protected attribute in rails, because .type is a ruby method. Hence you can't mass assign it. Rename the attribute (eg :account_type) & everything should work fine.

Comment: I think you could also avoid it by adding to your class `set_inheritance_column nil` should also undo the normal 'type' magic.